# How to hide layer by id?

Tags: adobe, photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script

I am writing `generator` plugin and I get document structure using method `generator.getDocumentInfo()`. It returns `document` object containing `layer` objects in tree structure. `document` object has property `document.id` and each layer has property `layer.id`.

Goal: I want to hide layer - I know only document id and layer id.

Problem: The only method to hide layer in generator plugin I found is `evaluateJSXString()` method. This is fine but I don't know how to access document by id and layer by id. According http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-cc-javascript-ref.pdf document has no `id` property and layer also has no `id` property. All I found is that `app.documents` is an array of documents (but index is not id) and `app.document[i].layers` is an array of layers but it contains only top level layers and each top level layer contains child layers.

The only option I see is to write JSX script which will first traverse `app.documents` array to find doc with for example matching file name and then it will search for a layer in `document.layers` tree structure..

1. Is there any other options?
2. How generator provides document and layer IDs when using generator.getDocumentInfo()? Is some generatpr-internal notation?

Comment: You might be able to use activeLayer or app.activeDocument.artLayers.getByName("myLayerName"); instead of traversing all the layers, Incidentally activeLayer doesn't return anything useful when multiple layers are selected.

Comment: unfortunately many layers may have same name...

Comment: Ugh, by id it is then! Unless you force the user to create a unique name :)

Answer (score 1):

I see this is an old question had the same question. I was able to come up with a solution using generator's method `evaluateJSXString`.  You can execute extendscript with `evaluateJSXString` with in your generator plugin.  There is no looping involved here. Just by `layerID`.

Note: `layerID` is a variable that holds the layer ID and it is concatenated to the string to be evaluated.

To show the layer:

```
  var changeVisibilityString = " var ref = new ActionReference(); \
                                  ref.putIdentifier(charIDToTypeID('Lyr '), " + layerID + " ); \
                                  var desc = new ActionDescriptor(); \
                                  desc.putReference(charIDToTypeID('null'), ref); \
                                  desc.putBoolean(charIDToTypeID('MkVs'), false); \
                                  executeAction( charIDToTypeID('Shw '), desc);"

    generator.evaluateJSXString(changeVisibilityString);
```

To hide the layer:

```
  var changeVisibilityString = " var ref = new ActionReference(); \
                                  ref.putIdentifier(charIDToTypeID('Lyr '), " + layerID + " ); \
                                  var desc = new ActionDescriptor(); \
                                  desc.putReference(charIDToTypeID('null'), ref); \
                                  desc.putBoolean(charIDToTypeID('MkVs'), false); \
                                  executeAction( charIDToTypeID('Hd  '), desc);"

    generator.evaluateJSXString(changeVisibilityString);
```